# Hyperledger Composer: install error (Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

When I try to install business network on Fabric, I get the error:

```
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: EOF
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: EOF
```

[image]

Logs of peer1 of org1: 
[image]

Most likely, this is because of wrong setting up a Fabric. Can anybody tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved. I just had to configure TLS in peers like so:

```
- CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
- CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
- CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
- CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
```

And set valid key in CA-contaner configuration:

`- FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=[Here path to key]`

The same path must be specified after `--ca.keyfile` in `command:` field.

Comment: I am getting this same error. I have verified the configuration which you have mentioned in above post. Is there anything which I need to further verify?

Comment: @ErvingGoffman can you please tell me where and how do i configure TLS ?

Comment: @SafvanKothawala pay attention to connection profile json file, if your docker compose yaml file is ok.

Comment: @sifavahora "services" section of your docker compose yaml. Write me to telegram, if you want to discuss details: https://t.me/goffmananderving or create new S/O post with your configs and logs.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting similar error-

```
Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
Command failed
```

The solution work for me is, I have to start the initial setup script commands as part of development environment installation.

> $ ./startFabric.sh
>
> $ ./createPeerAdminCard.sh

And then run the command to install the business network-

> $ composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna

Comment: This is a different error to the the original question - this is "UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed", but the original is "UNAVAILABLE: EOF"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but my fault was wrong env value for

- CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=

in docker-compose.yaml for every peer.